# META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, url, firefox, tags, refresh

I am using this bit of code to perform a refresh of the current page after a message is displayed.

```html
?>
<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' content='2;URL=./profile-manager/editprofile'>
<?
```

site.com/profile-manager/editprofile

The issue is the link refreshes fine in Google Chrome, but in Firefox it

site.com/profile-manager/editprofile/profile-manager/editprofile

it double links.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply remove the leading `.`:

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2; URL=/profile-manager/editprofile'>
```

If you have a website hosted on `www.example.org/test/file` and a link to `/file2`, it'll redirect you to `www.example.org/file2`. The leading `/` indicates that the file is or path starts at the root folder (which is `www.example.org/`). If you do not start with `/` and use `file2` instead, you would be redirected to `www.example.org/test/file2` which is located in the current folder. Using `./file2` should normally behave like Firefox does (the same way as using `file2`).